# Mi @Component no reconoce ninguna anotación

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, spring-security

Tengo un filtro el cual valida si el token que le llega es correcto, sin embargo, cuando hago referencia al Service de JWT que cree, me dice lo siguiente:
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot invoke "com.alura.configuration.JWTService.validarToken(String)" because "this.servicioJWT" is null
at com.alura.configuration.filterAutorizar.doFilterInternal(filterAutorizar.java:30) ~[classes/:na]**

Cabe aclarar que este servicio de JWT se utiliza en un controlador al momento de hacer el login y funciona correctamente. Probe hacer la verificacion directamente en el filter y tampoco me reconoce el @Value para poder obtener el secret para la firma del JWT.

```
@Component
public class filterAutorizar extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    JWTService servicioJWT;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (token != null && token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            token = token.substring(7).trim();

            try {
                servicioJWT.validarToken(token);

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());

            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}
```